# Javascript: Do processing when user has stopped typing

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a text box on a web page, whose value I want to send to a XMLHttpRequest. Now I want the user to just type the value, without pressing a button. But If i just send the request int he keyboard events, it will fire every time a key is pressed.

So basically I want something liek this

```
function KeyUpEvent()
{
  if (user is still typing)
    return;
  else 
    //do processing
}
```

It would be great if the solution could come from plain javascript or mootools. I dont want to use any other library.

Comment: A timer will never suffice. The user could simply be distracted or type slower than any time you choose as your timeout. My solution is the only reasonable solution and is how users expect to interact with fields and it doesn't require any buttons. If you don't know the length of the value, you have no idea whether the user is done. So then you risk transmitting a value the user didn't want or expect and their experience is simply frustrated by your timer, not enhanced. When it comes to UI experience, you're better off sticking with standard usage scenarios.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way this is usually done is by restarting a timer on the `keyup` event. Something like this:

```
var keyupTimer;
function keyUpEvent(){
   clearTimeout(keyupTimer);
   keyupTimer = setTimeout(sendInput,1000); // will activate when the user has stopped typing for 1 second
} 

function sendInput(){
    alert("Do AJAX request");
}
```

Comment: you are forgetting keyup, what if they decided to start typing again in 30 seconds? your event still fires

Comment: that is not a valid answer, that will fire the event [number of characters typed] number of times

Answer (score 9):

Basically, you want to start a timer on KeyUp, and when KeyUp starts again, reset the timer. When the user stops typing, the timer runs out, and your request can go at that point.

Example:

```
var timout_id;

function keyup_handler(event) {
  if (timout_id) {
    clearTimeout(timout_id);
  }

  timout_id = setTimeout(function(){
    alert('sending data: \n' + event.target.value)
  }, 800);
}
```

Just attach the function to the input using your preferred method, and replace the `alert` with your preferred action.

Of course there are many ways you could generalize this approach and make it more reusable, etc, but I think this illustrates the basic idea.

Answer (score 5):

I always use this simple function to handle a timer, that will fire a callback function, after the user has stopped typing for a specified amount of time:

```
var typewatch = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  }  
})();
```

Usage (example with MooTools):

```
$('textInput').addEvent('keyup', function(e){
  typewatch(function () {
    // executed only 500 ms after the last keyup event
    // make Ajax request
  }, 500);
});
```

The main difference between this solution and solutions from other answers is that *all* the timer logic is handled by the `typewatch` function itself, the event handler doesn't need to know anything about the timer, it just invokes the function. Also, there are no global variables to take care (the timer id is *not* stored on a global variable).

Answer (score 2):

You never know when a user is really "finished" typing.  The user might take a sneeze break, or a stretch break, or a coffee break, and then continue typing.

However, if you're implementing something like an autocomplete mechanism, you can set a timer (cf. `window.setTimeout(...)`) to see if the user hasn't typed anything in a certain amount of time.  If you get another key-up event while the timer is running, you can start the timer over.

Answer (score 1):

```
var keyTimer;
function onKeyUp(){
clearTimeout(keyTimer);
setTimeout(stoppedTyping,1500);
}
function stoppedTyping(){
// Profit! $$$
}
```

EDIT: Damn ninjas

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom jQuery event because I use this logic a lot:

```
jQuery.event.special.stoppedtyping = {
  setup: function(data, namespaces) {
    jQuery(this).bind('keyup', jQuery.event.special.stoppedtyping.keyuphandler);
  },
  teardown: function(namespaces) {
    jQuery(this).bind('keyup', jQuery.event.special.stoppedtyping.keyuphandler);
  },
  keyuphandler: function(e) {
    var interval = 1000;
    var el = this;

    if (jQuery.data(this, 'checklastkeypress') != null) {
      clearTimeout(jQuery.data(this, 'checklastkeypress'));
    }

    var id = setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery(el).trigger('stoppedtyping');
    }, interval);
    jQuery.data(this, 'checklastkeypress', id);
  }
};
```

You can use it like this:

```
$('input.title').bind('stoppedtyping', function() {
  // run some ajax save operation
});
```

For some reason I could never get it to work with .live( ... ). I'm not sure why...

Answer (score -1):

Use onBlur and maybe an onKeyDown to check for the user pressing the return/enter key.

Comment: Seriously!? Down-voting this when it's the only real means to know when a user is done typing?! That is, they've left the field or pressed a key indicating they want to submit. Otherwise, there's no way to know. Not a timer because they may have simply been distracted.